# How to use SF Symbol programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

How do you access the icons provided by SF Symbols? Things like sun and star icons. How can someone access these in code? This is what I have so far below (simplified example):

```
@IBOutlet weak var favoriteSymbol: UIImageView!
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    favoriteSymbol.image = // How to access Apple icon here, like "star.filled"?
}
```

Do I need to download the image and then add it to the Assets folder, or are they built in? In case it matters, I'm using storyboards. There is an image already placed on the storyboard, which I will change to the "star.filled" icon programatically.

Comment: `UIImage(systemName:"star.filled")`

Comment: You should watch "Introducing SF Symbols" - WWDC19

Comment: @matt "favoriteSymbol.image = UIImage(systemName:"star.filled")" doesn't seem to work, nothing shows up. Is ".image" not correct?

Comment: No, the problem is that there is no icon called `"star.filled"`. You made that up. I simply told you how to make the _call_. If you want an actual icon, you need to use a name that is really the name of an icon. For example, there _is_ an icon called `"star.fill"`. Notice the subtle difference...

Comment: The documentation for [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) should help you access the images.

Comment: @matt I see, I made a typo. Thank you, this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use an SF Symbol, use `systemName`:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
```

**Note**: The specified icon MUST exist within the SF Symbols library. However, you can make custom SF Symbols as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10250/)

To view the SF Icons library, Download [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/) app or take a [look at this tutorial](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/sf-symbols-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

for use system icons you need iOS 13 or newest, and install SF Symbols,
and do:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")
```

Xcode automatically will get the icon.

[image]

Comment: FYI - Xcode has nothing to do with this.